# How to change secure-file-priv option in MySQL on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu-20.04, into-outfile

I am trying to use OUTFILE on Ubuntu 20.04 and getting this error:
MySQL server version: 8.0.21

Code:

```
mysql> select * into OUTFILE '/home/yash/Desktop/data2.txt' from ticket;

ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

I tried many solutions but it didn't work on Ubuntu 20.04

If anyone can give a solution for Ubuntu 20.04 and MySQL 8.0.21 then it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

to see the directory that MySQL thinks that it is secure to load or save files.

You have now two options:

1. Move your file to the directory specified by secure-file-priv.
2. Disable secure-file-priv. This must be removed from startup and cannot be modified dynamically. So you have to change it in my.conf

In my.con you should find `secure-file-priv=` and change it to

```
[mysql]
secure-file-priv='/home/yash/Desktop/'
```

So that your desktop will become a save directory.

And you can **disable** the secure file option, **which is not recommended**  by

```
[mysql]
secure-file-priv=''
```

Comment: I've added the line `secure_file_priv='/home/rodrigo/Documents/'` to `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`, restarted the service with `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`, but on Workbench (after giving the password again), `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";` is still giving me `/var/lib/mysql-files/`. Why?

Comment: conf ahs chapters as you see and if you place it wrong it will not work. Also there mybe mire than one conf file in linux

Comment: @nbk thanks dude, best answer ever, peace my perro

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you want to store the result of the query in a text file try '`tee`' MySQL command
Try this in your MySQL prompt

```
tee /home/yash/Desktop/data2.txt;

select * from ticket;
```

Are you using any shell script or connecting MySQL DB from the terminal?

If not working then disable "`secure_file_priv`" in `mysqld.cnf` then restart.
set `secure-file-priv = ""` in `mysqld.cnf` file and the check `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";` and you get the below sample output

```
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| secure_file_priv |       |
```